# Why do minotaur need glasses when their eyes are at the sides?

Tags: biology, creature-design, mythical-creatures, vision

Minotaur is a race of mythical bipedal creature that is half man half cow, suppose they got integrated into our society due to them being relatively friendly and intelligent so we are starting to share a lot of things in common. My question is since their head shared almost similar biology to a cow especially the position of their eyes then why do they put on glasses? Unlike us their eyes are located at the sides of the head which gives them almost 360 degree of view but for us glasses help to correct short sightedness etc which doesn't bother them right? I must say I would prefer a medical reason if possible otherwise no reason for their to put on a pair of glasses.

Comment: Same reason as the rest of us. He sits in an office chair 9 hours a day staring at a computer screen. In truth he secretly yearns to quit his job and go do physical labor until his muscles are tired instead of atrophied like they are now. "Minotaur, where are those TPS reports?! I needed those yesterday!"

Comment: As someone with bad eyesight, the severe misunderstanding of why people wear glasses pains me.

Comment: If that were true, we could always close one eye and get perfect 20/20 vision on the other eye.

Comment: *"Why do minotaur need glasses when their eyes are at the sides?"* // Glasses are about focus (long & short vision) not triangulation, you understand that right?

Comment: Rhinos have eyes on the sides on their heads. Rhinos are also extremely aggressive, because they have very poor vision and can't really see anything beyond about 30 meters/100 feet. More often than not, animals in general don't like not being able to see something without having to get extremely close just to tell what exactly it is, especially so if you're a wild animal that often has to deal with predation to the point you have eyes on the sides of your head to be Able to spot predators.

Comment: I just occurred to be - maybe by "glasses" you meant "3D glasses"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are confusing field of view with sharpness of view.

- Field of view is, roughly speaking since I am not an optician, how much of the 3D space around one's head it can be viewed by the eyes. This is affected by the relative position of the eyes in the head.
- Sharpness of view, again roughly speaking since I am not an optician, is how well objects at different distances are focused and resolved by each eye. This is what is affected by myopia, astigmatism or presbyopia, and is related to the optical performance of the eye. The degrees used to measure this are not the same, geometrical degrees used for the previous one.

And a grazer who cannot tell a poisonous grass from an edible one because of its poor sight will surely benefit from a pair of glasses, despite having its eyes on the sides of its head.

Answer (score 2):

**Because they like reading and going to art galleries/cinema.**

The remarkable thing about prisms is that they can act as almost perfect mirrors with little loss of brightness:

[[image: Part of telescope containing prisms producing 90 degree turn.1]

<sup>Baader prism, 2022, [commercial-link](https://optcorp.com/products/baader-prism-diagonal-t-2-90-degrees-32mm), no affiliation, fair usage.</sup>

A couple of these would enable the creature to read more efficiently than with one eye, and see stereoscopically at a much greater angle than without. The marvellous thing about this is that all cinema would seem like 3D, in comparison to the usual narrow vision/single-eyed-sight they're used to.

Cows don't have the same high-resolution central-focus that humans and in the extreme eagles do, their vision is pretty low definition all over, so it also has the advantage that the normally wide and low resolution vision could be used to-the-max, the image can be focussed so that the important parts, the cinema-screen/book/painting can take-up the whole field of view, enabling total appreciation of what's being watched by making use of the whole of the eye's potential.